# Handle Leading Spaces and Special Character in React js onInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to prevent user to enter multiple spaces and special character in input field. I have done it .....
But when user paste data that contain more then one spaces it is able to paste I want to trim first letter start leading spaces only in case if user write something or paste something.
My handle Change code is Mention below

```
handleChange = event => {
    //Carret Position
    const caret = event.target.selectionStart;
    const element = event.target;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      element.selectionStart = caret;
      element.selectionEnd = caret;
    });
    console.log(event.target.value)
    // Expression to Match every field except Email
    var regExpr = /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g;
    var myValue = event.target.value;
    var myName = event.target.name;

    if (caret == 0 || caret <= 1) {
      myValue = myValue.trim();
    }

    if (myName == "cliaNumber") {
      myValue = myValue ? myValue : "";
      myValue = myValue.trim();
      myValue = myValue.replace(regExpr, "");
    } else if (myName == "email") {
      myValue = myValue ? myValue : "";
      myValue = myValue;
    } else if (myName == "officePhoneNum"){
      myValue = myValue ? myValue : "";
      myValue = myValue;
    }else {
      myValue = myValue.replace(regExpr, "");
    }
    this.setState({
      pModel: {
        ...this.state.pModel,
        [myName]: myValue.toUpperCase()
      }
    });

  };
```

I don't want to use onInput at the same time or Can't replace my handleChange with onInput.
Can some suggest me some good solutions?
Thanks

Comment: please format your code properly